# Finding the area of the shaded square inside a square created by connecting point-opposite midpoint

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

If the lines intersect the vertices of the square. The area of the square is $1$ and the lines also intersect the midpoints of the square lines. How to find the area of shaded region?

[image]

Comment: See also: [Area of a square inside a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2518341)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Area of a square inside a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518341/area-of-a-square-inside-a-square)

Comment: @MartinSleziak an answered question from 2013 is usually not a duplicate of a question from 2017

Comment: @Henry This was discussed at lengths on meta: [Original post marked as duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16417) (and [several other posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/16417)). The direction in which duplicates are closed shouldn't be decided simply by the time posted.