# Show the congruence $YZ+JK=JF$ in this square with trapezoids, triangles constructed with square's midpoints

Tags: geometry, congruences-geometry

Show that $YZ+JK=JF$

I tried Pythagorean theorem.

[image]

OG: [Area of a square inside a square created by connecting point-opposite midpoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518341/area-of-a-square-inside-a-square-created-by-connecting-point-opposite-midpoint/341797#341797)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\angle{ACB} = \theta$. Now apply $\tan\theta$, it gives $\frac12$. It is same with angles $DFC, KLF, LAY,$ so these angles are equal.

Hence $\triangle{AXB}, \triangle{LYZ}, \triangle{FJK}$ and $\triangle{CED}$ are congruent by ASA rule.

We can also see some similar triangles. These are $\triangle{LYZ} $ is similar to $\triangle{LJF}$, and etc.
So $LY = YJ$ and etc.
Also $2YZ = JF$ and $2JK = CE$. But $CE = JF$, so $YZ = JK = \frac{1}{2}JF$.

Hence $YZ + JK = JF$ (Hence Proved)

Comment: Why is theta 26.56 degrees?  @Congruent

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: $tan(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2} \iff \theta \approx 26.56$ degree

Comment: I just took theta to get the triangles congruent. You can also use SAS rule of congruency.